# AMQ222244: Unable to check if message expired artemis 2.17.0

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0, and I observed that producer are getting stuck after a while. Producers are still using the ActiveMQ 5.16.3 client library.

The lock observed on client side:

```
"Thread-13422" #14272 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055a74d20a000 nid=0x7a46 waiting on condition [0x00007fa5523dd000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006b2a00338> (at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.FutureResponse.getResult(FutureResponse.java:48)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1388)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1428)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1323)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1974)
    - locked <0x00000006b2a00488> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:288)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:223)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:95)
    - locked <0x00000006b2a00508> (a org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer)
```

On the server side I saw this exception:

```
AMQ222244: Unable to check if message expired: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.NonExistentPage: Invalid messageNumber passed = PagePositionImpl [pageNr=1224, messageNr=1233, recordID=2178453908, fileOffset=9056626] on null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageCursorProviderImpl.getMessage(PageCursorProviderImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageSubscriptionImpl.queryMessage(PageSubscriptionImpl.java:634)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl.getPagedMessage(PagedReferenceImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.PagedReferenceImpl.getMessage(PagedReferenceImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.checkExpired(QueueImpl.java:3815)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.deliver(QueueImpl.java:2981)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.access$2400(QueueImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl$DeliverRunner.run(QueueImpl.java:4163)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
```

What is the root cause of that issue? How can we prevent it?

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this? If so, have you reproduced this on the latest release? The stack-trace on the client indicates a delay when _sending_ a message, but the exception on the broker indicates a problem delivering a message to a consumer. It's not clear that these two things are causally related. A thread-dump from the broker when the producer is stalled may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Ok I ll get a thread dump and share

Comment: Any word on reproducibility on the latest release?

Comment: Latest release is on java11. We are stuck on java 8. I can try with 2.19.1 but issue is occurring on UAT env and it will take time to reach that stage. I check the thread dump and didn't find anything anormal

Comment: The world is (finally) moving on from Java 8. I would strongly encourage you to do the same. The 2.19.x branch is only going to get bug fixes. It won't get any new features.

Comment: Yes. I ll do that